# Spring Data JPA only for fetch and not persist

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Spring boot and Spring data jpa and connecting to DB2 for a legacy DB. My requirement is I'm adding a relationship. It works when I use query for fetching. Earlier I had to read only from these tables, but recently I needed to insert in few of the tables, and that time it is failing. Please find my table details below.

```
User -> userId, name, address, regCode, subjectCode
UserType -> userId, regCode, typeCode (userId & regCode are primary keys)
RegData -> regCode, subjectCode, name, description (regCode & subjectCode are primary keys)
```

And my entity details as below.

**User.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String regCode;
    private String subjectCode;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "regCode", referencedColumnName = "REG_CODE")
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "USERID")
    private UserType  userType ;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "regCode", referencedColumnName = "REG_CODE")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "subjectCode", referencedColumnName = "SUBJECT_CODE")) })
    private RegData  regData ;
}
```

**UserType.java & UserTypeId.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class UserType implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserTypeId id;
    private int typeCode;
}

@Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserTypeId implements Serializable {

    private Long userId;
    private String regCode;
}
```

**RegData.java & RegDataId.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class RegData implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RegDataId id;
    private String name
    private String desc

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reg_code", referencedColumnName = "REG_CODE")
    private Registration registration;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class RegDataId implements Serializable {
    private String  regCode;
    private String  subjectCode;
}
```

Using `userRepository` I'm able to fetch user data along with user type and RegData. But I got a usecase where I need to insert new User to DB, along with that I need to insert new User Type also.

I tried creating new user and user type and setting user type object to user and then tried calling `save()` using `userRepositry`. But it failed with DB2 responding with error 121 as the insert query had same columns repeated.

What I tried was annotating the fields as Transient. Then I 'm able to save User and UserType separately. But fetching is not working. I have to do another fetch call manually to set the data.

What is the best approach to save the User and UserType while fetch works fine? (I can set the RegData to user object by fetching from DB during save call.

**UPDATE**

Below is the insert Query I'm getting from hibernate when I try to call save()

**Code**

```
int nextId = //Next Id value assigned manually
User user = new User()
user.setUserId(nextId)
//Setting Values
UserType type = new UserType()
UserTypeId id = new UserTypeId();
id.setUserId(nextId);
type.setId(id);
user.setUserType(type);
user.setRegData(//Getting object from DB);
userrepository.save(user);
```

**Generated Inert Query:**

```
insert into USER (REG_CODE, subject_code, NAME, SUBJECT_CODE, userid, reg_code, USERID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

As you can see same columns are repeated because of the relationship. How to fix this?

Comment: How are the IDs created? If they are not automatically created by the database, then you can't cascade inserts. You can try with `@OneToOne(cascade = {})` to not cascade any operations. `@Transient` tells hibernate that the annotated field does not come from database, so that should be removed. `@JoinColumn(name = "regCode", referencedColumnName = "REG_CODE")` I am not sure if `REG_CODE` is correct for you, as you never show that the column exists anywhere. Lastly, `@EmbeddedId` is not needed for multiple ID columns. You can simply annotate multiple fields with `@Id`

Comment: Once you added `cascade = {}` to the mappings and removed `@Transient`, you should be able to fetch data with a single call. To persist the data, you should insert the entities each on their own and make sure that you do so in the correct order as you might have foreign keys which could fail the inserts if done in the wrong order

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `regCode` is from different table. The Id is not generated automatically. I'm setting the value manually. If I remove Transient, fetch will work. But to insert User object I'm getting error. Will post the insert query I got from Debug while saving

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have updated the question with insert query. The columns are getting repeated in generated insert query

Comment: Remove the fields `private String regCode; private String subjectCode;` you don't need those in the user class as you have them in the `regData` field